# Is there any reason for putting humans.txt except of acknowledgement?

Tags: robots.txt

Are there any valid reasons of putting [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/)? The only reason I see so far is to give credit to the team who created the site, and open source libraries it is using.

Comment: Which reasons would be *valid*?

Comment: Google seems to use humans.txt as a way to recruit, since all it does is point to their careers page. That's about as close to a "valid" reason as I can think of. Otherwise it's only point seems to be self-promotion of developers/designers.

Comment: @unor any reason, that potentially can give you more than you spend on implementing it, and does not harm you. So if there will be something to cover my 5 minutes of creating the file, I will take this as a valid reason.

Comment: The way the voting on answers has gone, I don't think this was ever really a question but turf. (compare the timing of downvotes/answer acceptance, clearly shows collusion)

Comment: @JamesRyan just because someone downvoted your answer, it does not mean that the question is bad. Also if you would stop comparing downvote/acceptance and see my profile - you would see that I was not the one downvoted it. Also voting on answers has nothing to do with how bad is the question. So stop behaving childish - be a grown up man.

Comment: Two downvotes on my answer came in together at the same time as the other answer was accepted. Given the age of the question, the likelyhood of that happening by chance and not through you rigging the voting are slim.  If anyone is being childish it is you in forcing through the answer you want to advertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bots will be sad when they only find a 404.

Humans will be sad when they don’t find one.

Technologies will be sad when they don’t get [praised](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44764/17633).

Contributors will be sad when they are [credited](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/33701/17633) nowhere.

Services will be sad when they can’t [list](http://humanstxt.org/humans/) or [list](http://www.humanssearch.com/?show) or … your site.

Webmasters will be [sad](http://perishablepress.com/humans-txt/) when sad bots create so much overhead.

Comment: a) with the exception of people promoting this initiative no one is using it b) there is no standard format for this file so it will never usable c) it is not even html for site visitors to use so it is not fit for purpose

Comment: @JamesRyan: a) What do you mean by "use"? [google.com](http://www.google.com/humans.txt), [html5boilerplate.com](http://html5boilerplate.com/humans.txt), [github.com](https://github.com/humans.txt) have a humans.txt, for example. b) That’s intentional. c) It doesn’t want to *replace* HTML pages giving credits.

Comment: a) consume. So its b) deliberately non machine readable and c) deliberately redundant.  So how is it useful?

This answer tries to attach emotion to inanimate objects to attempt to make you feel that it is worthwhile without giving any technical justifaction whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is completely pointless and confuses the reasons for robots.txt.  The whole website by default is already for humans.

Info about who made the website already has a place in the website itself either visibly or in the meta tags. **Using an unconventional magic file is not good practice.**

Comment: "confuses the reasons for robots.txt" - why?

Comment: because robots.txt tells bots how to use the website. Their proposed humans.txt follows the same naming convention and even refers to robots.txt yet it isn't there to tell humans how to use the website